# Detecting if specific jQuery.get() is in progress?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ajax-request

How do you detect if a specific ajax request is in progress, I can use done and fail to detect when it is finished and on fail, but is there a way to find if it is in progress?

```
var prog = false;
var ajxReq = $.get(url, function (response) {
    // insert response into container
})
.done (function () { prog = false; })
.fail (function () { });

var prog1 = false;
var ajxReq1 = $.get(url, function (response) {
    // insert response into container
})
.done (function () { prog1 = false; })
.fail (function () { });
```

I want to change prog variable value to true if ajxReq in progress and prog1 variable value to true if ajxReq1 in progress

Youssef

Comment: start the value as `var prog = true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for something for all your application's ajax then you can always use `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` for that:

```
var isAjaxRunning = false;

$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
     isAjaxRunning = true;
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
      isAjaxRunning = false;
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/
http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstop/

Otherwise simply do something like this:

```
var prog = false;
var ajxReq = $.get(url, function (response) {
    prog = true; 
    // insert response into container
})
.done (function () { prog = false; })
```

Comment: Read my code again. If you are talking about all the ajax calls in your application then look at my first example. If we are talking about a specific ajax call then look at my second example. I am simply changing the prog value to true when I begin an ajax and returning it back to false when the ajax is ended.

Comment: Thanks, your second method is working fine, for some reason sublime wasn't saving the file so I thought this wasn't working but after restarting sublime this worked :)